# Add a property to my JSON file using JOLTTRANSFORMJSON APACHE NIFI

Tags: json, etl, apache-nifi, jolt

> Im trying to use apache nifi to practice transformation data, I have been trying to use the GetFile to take my 4 JSON files, my objective is to transform this 4 in 1, but is important to me to remeber where are thoose from because 1 makes references to posts, one to ads, and one to videos
> I have been using Update attribute to save the filename where they become and the the update attribute to update the data and then with merge make just 1 file
>
> I don have problem to merge the files, but when I try to add the new propertie i cant make it well

```
{
  "impressions_history_ads_seen": [
    {
      "string_map_data": {
        "Time": {
          "timestamp": 1705789300
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "string_map_data": {
        "Time": {
          "timestamp": 1705789746
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "string_map_data": {
        "Author": {
          "value": "twdss"
        },
        "Time": {
          "timestamp": 1705790493
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "string_map_data": {
        "Author": {
          "value": "mitprofessionaled"
        },
        "Time": {
          "timestamp": 1705809684
        }
      }
    }
```

> this is my original json
>
> i want to add at the same level of Author and Time the value of type_interaction and give the >filename value
>
> in the update data

`filename = ${filename:substringBeforeLast('.')}`

```
> in the JoltTransformJSON
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
            "*":&,
            "type_interaction":"${filename}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below jolt spec. Keep in mind when you do shift spec and you want to maintain the same structure then you need to specify the complete structure in RHS as traversed.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.[&2].&1.&",
            "#${filename}": "&3.[&2].&1.type_interaction"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Also when you want to set a default in shift spec, you specify the value in the LHS proceeded with #. Since Nifi allows Expression Language in the Jolt spec, the flowfile attribute ${filename} will be replaced with the actual value before transformation.